# Spring [Boot] Security and Oracle IDCS: [invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Spring Security is giving me **"[invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set"** after getting the signing keys from JWK Set URI. The signing keys are shown below. I am using Spring Security 5.3.3.RELEASE.

```
{
    "keys":[
        {
            "x5t#S256":"_wJqnmEgaue0Hrr5C6WXbQKomIOcacggUeRlnGP0LBA",
            "x5t":"v1UrKX9lqCSfldbxprXRM7BoT9o",
            "key_ops":[
                "verify",
                "encrypt"
            ],
            "e":"AQAB",
            "kty":"RSA",
            "x5c":[
                "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",
                "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"
            ],
            "alg":"RS256",
            "n":"6JcGWtVqYf7JPvt6XGKV3wPBfFDCDkBCIbxgj1XrPeFRJzdZqozLCro4EpmL9ccAKugpG5AHDFLhPAn0Uqu4p1MMXKvoaJ6q6_rXjXK95qFam8eKFb5y2GeoqJbzhCoEi8Vj8VUhLt-jQiZJJPpG75TWWo_2OXv93JA1LEHQ0lGQoZ76RHaHvbjkkNOtc8g0VVsvo3m5MB9_k8n55MTGxzgtxX6z6qIyQx_fpJL2AoVd-T8wLo3OyI6DkVRaGZsXrB_IrZ0XWigb7ztHxJvaqzCmxkay-LvyHCJqoy5nIXSA-dU2FrBuWA4XzIR6cLY-amH6GZ83u2_kWqYWE8dlYw",
            "kid":"SIGNING_KEY"
        }
    ]
}
```

Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.createOidcToken(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:226) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:155) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:185) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) [spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:152) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:126) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.createOidcToken(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:223) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

More info would be needed in order to best assist you on this, but a JWT is decoded (by anyone) and signature is verified (with the signing key). Your error indicates issue is w/ the decode (not signature verification) which means signing key has nothing to do w/ it. Error indicates the gotten ID token is not a JWT (and thus an error in the decode). To be able to further assist, we need to know how the ID token was gotten.